# pdfjs_rails: Fullscreen/PresentationMode not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, rubygems, pdf.js

I am using the pdfjs_rails gem for my application (https://github.com/shyammohankanojia/pdfjs_rails)

The problem is, I cannot see the "presentation mode" button.
I need to be able to view the file in fullscreen.
I render my pdf viewer like so:

```
%iframe{ frameborder: "0", height: "500", scrolling: "no", src: "/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=#{file}", style: "border: 0", width: "100%" }
```

[image]

Thanks

**EDIT**:
Based in the answer from @CodeMaker, I used:

```
%iframe{ frameborder: "0", height: "500", scrolling: "no", src: "/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=#{file}", style: "border: 0", width: "100%", webkitallowfullscreen: "", mozallowfullscreen: "", allowfullscreen: "" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for pdf_rails use this

```
%iframe{ frameborder: "0", height: "500", scrolling: "no", src: "/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=#{file}", style="width: 100%; height: 1100px; display:inline-block "  scrolling="yes" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen frameborder="no" }
```

Comment: I am receiving a long error when I use this (maybe missing some commas, etc.)?, is ```webkitallowfullscreen``` supposed to be a class for the div?

Comment: I got it, I used:  ```%iframe{ frameborder: "0", height: "500", scrolling: "no", src: "/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=#{file}", style: "border: 0", width: "100%", webkitallowfullscreen: "", mozallowfullscreen: "", allowfullscreen: "" }```